# Use filter method on multidimensional arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having a multidimensional array, I would like to filter it, so only the array which has a word ending with underscore '_'  is left. I have already accomplished this task using loops.

```
function searchNames( logins ){
   var arr = logins;
    var reg = /\w+_\b/;
    var newAr = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(var x = 0; x < arr[i].length; x++){
       if(arr[i][x].match(reg)){
       newAr.push(arr[i])
       }
     }

   }
  return newAr;
}
```

Is there any way to do the same using 
Array.prototype.filter() method. According to MDN reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you can do similar things but I can`t figure out how to filter the arrays inside the array. All of my attempts to use filter method inside of another filter method failed.

Comment: Why don't you even comment when you get an answer ?

Comment: Sorry, new to this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the filter method a useful block:

```
array = [["hello_","cat"],["dog","dog"]];

arrayTest = function(arr){
    resp = false;
    arr.forEach(function(str){
       if(str.slice(-1) === "_") resp = true;
    });
    return resp;
}

result = array.filter(arrayTest);
```

or if you're really married to your regex:

```
array = [["hello_","cat"],["dog","dog"]];
regex = /\w+_\b/;

arrayTest = function(arr){
    resp = false;
    arr.forEach(function(str){
       if(str.match(regex)) resp = true;
    });
    return resp;
}

result = array.filter(arrayTest);
```

Comment: That works, thank you, I totally forgot about forEach method!

Comment: Totes totes totes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want

```
var newArr = arr.filter(subArr => subArr.some(e=>/\w+_\b/.test(e)));
```